# Singleton bean in Prototype bean in Spring Context

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Typically in Spring Context if a prototype bean is injected in a singleton bean, property of parent class overrides prototype bean scope. However what will happen if a singleton scope bean is injected in prototype bean scope. 
Still using get bean of the inner bean will return with new instance of inner bean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, all instances of `prototype` bean will share the same instance of the `singleton` bean.
Example:

```
@Service
public class SingletonBean {
    private int id;
    private static int static_id = 0;

    public SingletonBean() {
        id = static_id++;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SingletonBean [id=" + id + "]";
    }

}
```

```
@Service
@Scope("prototype")
public class PrototypeBean {

    @Autowired
    private SingletonBean singletonBean;
    private int id;

    private static int static_id = 0;

    public PrototypeBean() {
        id = static_id++;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "id=" + id + ", PrototypeBean [singletonBean=" + singletonBean + "]";
    }
}
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        PrototypeBean beanA = context.getBean(PrototypeBean.class);
        PrototypeBean beanB = context.getBean(PrototypeBean.class);

        System.out.println(beanA); //id=0, PrototypeBean [singletonBean=SingletonBean [id=0]]
        System.out.println(beanB); //id=1, PrototypeBean [singletonBean=SingletonBean [id=0]]
    }
}

</code>
```

Comment: @gWombat I'm running the same example but it creates 3 instances of the prototype bean, I'm putting one log in constructor (it print 3 times instead of 2) and just change the `id = static_id++;` to `id = ++static_id;` (it's printing 3). Can you clarify why this is 3 instead of 2 in both condition

Answer (score 0):

> Typically in Spring Context if a prototype bean is injected in a
>   singleton bean, property of parent class overrides prototype bean
>   scope.

That is true,but not always, you can override that using Lookup method injection, which make you able to inject new prototype object in every request , check [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection) for a complete example about it,

for your main question the singleton is created once when the context is loaded and then whoever called this singleton the context give the same instance , without taking on consideration who making the call